# Problematic Logout of ASP.Net Local Identity when implementing External Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, owin

**TLDR**. I have a ASP.NET portal  with an external login only ( no local identity ). The users keep getting logged out automatically every 3-4 minutes, forcing the portal to re-authenticate itself against the external service

**MVC5/OWIN/Identity3**

We have a central authentication server, which works with a modified o-auth2 workflow. Basically, all the user/profile/authorization details are retrieved from that server once the user has logged in.

Note that there is no concept of a local identity since we don't store any of the above data permanently except as a claim in the current Identity of the logged in user.

To implement this, we have created a custom middleware which authenticates itself against the external system ( similar to the Google Auth Katana implementation )

The system works perfectly except that it seems to 'forget' the user every 180 seconds or so...

Essentially what happens is that even though the '.AspNet.ApplicationCookie' is sent back the portal, the portal treats the user as being not logged in and redirects the user back to the external server.

**Relevant section of Startup.Auth.cs**

```cs
        // Commented out since we do NOT want local identity

        //app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(2,0,0)
        };
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieOptions.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Based on https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/tree/v3.0.1/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google
        // GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationMiddleware , GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler,

        // Essentialy, redirects user for login to external server
        // Get the relavent data and creates a claims identity
        // Declares user logged in. 
        app.UseCustomAuthentication(new CustomAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientKey"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"],
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "CustomAuth",
            BeforeRedirectPath = new PathString("/Account/BeforeAuthRedirect")
        });
```

**Code in Account controller.**

```cs
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        var result = new ChallengeResult(
                        "CustomAuth",
                        Url.Action("CallBackURL", "Account", new
                        {
                            ReturnUrl = returnUrl
                        })
                );


        return result;
    }
```

**Relevant code of ChallengeResult**

```cs
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
        context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
```

My guess is that somewhere down the pipe the cookie is not getting decrypted correctly and its generating a null identity.

If someone could help me figure out where exactly does the ApplicationCookie gets decrypted and the Identity rehydrated, would be extremely helpful.

Any other ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for OWIN you are required to at least have in-memory local database. you don't need to store the details in a persistent store like a db., but you do need to use data structures that mimic this behavior.

where are the claims being stored? are you persisting them in the view?
there needs to be a place that refers to the claim and user's session.

I suspect the reason your users are redirected to external authentication, is purely because your app is not tracking who is authorized with what claim.

---

UPDATE:
reading through the comments we are both saying the same thing, but in different terms.

OWIN has its own version of an authentication manager in the `IAuthenticationManager` interface which is attached to your HttpContext object. To access it you use:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

Sign-ins work with `ClaimsIdentity` , which contain user information. The user detail that is stored is stored in claims.

create a helper function that can act as this context for authentication

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
}
```

your sign in helper

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, <userid>));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, <name>));


var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        AllowRefresh = true,
        IsPersistent = isPersistent,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
    }, identity);
```

these are the building blocks of your cookie and identity for owin
many pieces are missing, but you must have these to accomplish your claims for the cookies.

this is done all in memory if you are not persisting the claims another way.

Comment: AFIAK, the identity itself is directly encrypted and stored in the cookie. You don't need to have any structures in place since a local login does not need to "exist" per se except in memory.

Comment: example for this is here --> https://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/using-owin-external-login-without-asp-net-identity/

Comment: you are correct JustShrey its encrypted, however ASP.NET doesn't know what the heck it means because it's relevance to the user needs to be persisted between views.

Comment: "The relevance to the user", not sure i understand. A user in system is essentially defined by the ClaimsIdentity stored in the cookie. Once that is set, we use User.Identity to reference to other parts in the system. This actually works as long as the user is refreshing the page within a few minutes.

Comment: Problem comes in if the user does not refresh/ navigate to a page within those few mins, in that case for some reason, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false, which cause the redirection to the external service for a re-login

Comment: which is why you are required to persist the claim to avoid refresh /navigation within those few min. the session needs to stay in memory.

Comment: mate, i think you are missing the point. The claim and the identity is persisted in the cookie itself. The session is linked to the identifier in that cookie. I can see that in the store ( we have persistance of sessions via sql server )

Comment: ViewData["store"], so when the cookie is not authenticating the user, check the store first before redirecting them to authenticate.

Comment: Umm.. this is at the middleware level, ergo it wont even hit the action since the middleware would have already rejected the user and redirected to the external login.

Comment: This is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. So posting for anyone else who might encounter this problem.

The key to solving this was the need to regularly refresh the page. This was happening because the external cookie ( which was being set by the Custom Authentication ) was not explicitly setting the expiration date therefore causing the cookie to default to 60 seconds.

Due to the fact that sliding expiration was on, repeatedly refreshing the page kept the session alive.

Under normal circumstances, when you have a local identity this does not matter because the main cookie Auth has a longer duration. But when you don't have the local identity the main cookie middleware code below ...

```cs
    var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(2,0,0)
    };
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(cookieOptions.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
```

**does NOT set the cookie**, it just reads it on subsequent page load to re-hydrate the identity.

This is the reason we keep the  external cookie name to be the same as the application cookie name.

```cs
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

From an implementation standpoint, when you generate the Authentication Ticket in your middleware, remember to set the expiration date explicitly and persist it if needed . i.e

```cs
    //Inside CustomAuthenticationHandler

    private async Task<bool> InvokeReplyPathAsync()
    {
        if (Options.CallbackPath.HasValue && Options.CallbackPath == Request.Path)
        {
            _//InvokeReplyPathAsync: - Match {Request.Path}");
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = await AuthenticateAsync();
            if (ticket == null)
            {
                // InvokeReplyPathAsync:  Null Ticket Recieved. Unable to redirect.
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                return true;
            }
            //***** IMPORTANT ******WILL CAUSE SEEMINGLY RANDOM LOGOUT IF NOT SET ******* 
            // Defaults to 60 Seconds if not set
            ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(2); // Set as per your application need
            ticket.Properties.IsPersistent = true; 
            ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
```